# How do I use a current source for a pulsed voltage in LT Spice?

Tags: simulation, ltspice, current-source

For an LT Spice simulation I was doing of a transformer, I would like to set the current to 3 amps for a power supply, but I'm not sure how to use a current source for that.  I tried putting two current sources to represent the current of a pulsed power source, but the current through the resistor still isn't limited to 3 amps.  I'm not sure if it would effect the output much because it wouldn't draw much more than 3 amps, but I would like to know how to do it. 
Here's the schematic and the current reading through the resistor R4:
[image]  [image: Readings:]

Comment: Why did you chose the sources you have?

Comment: What do you mean by "use a current source for a pulsed voltage"? That makes no sense to me. Tell us what you are **trying to accomplish** with all of the sources you have in the schematic.

Comment: Trying to make any sense of this but this is way too unclear. As Elliot writes: explain what you're trying to achieve because it looks now like you expect behavior that cannot be modeled this way.

Comment: What's wrong with using two coupled inductors?

Comment: Tom, this is a classic example of "garbage in, garbage out." Spice is a perfectly serviceable tool in the hands of someone who knows how to use it. But you can't "hunt and peck" out a working circuit with it. I'm not chastiziing you. Just pointing out that you almost certainly don't know how to use Spice and that you need to write more about your goals. Do you just want to set up a Spice simulation for a typical "transformer + bridge diode rectifier + following filter and regulator?" Is that it?

Comment: To describe what I would like to accomplish, I would like to set the current during both Von time periods to 3 amps.

Comment: I still don't understand. You simply restated what you already wrote. You added nothing. So I remain as ignorant as I was, beforehand. If you feel like adding more about the context and situation, perhaps more can be added that may help. But for now, I'm no further along and can't be of any further help.